# Strings from input, where they should be stored, dynamic or static data?

Tags: mips

I'm learning the basis of assembly language using MIPS and the MARS simulator.
The title encloses my question, but I'll try to extend it with an example. 
Suppose we want to read a string from the keyboard (maximum 200 characters). We have to ways to proceed

1) We allocate 201 bytes on the static data segment, do the system call to read the string and then refer to it by "string" address

```
.data
string:     .space  201

.text
li  $v0, 8
la  $a0, string
li  $a1, 201
syscall
```

2) We request by the sbrk function (the only available on MARS) 201 consecutive bytes on the heap, and then we fill them with the input string.

```
li  $v0, 9
la  $a0, 201
syscall
move    $s0, $v0

li  $v0, 8
move    $a0, $s0
li  $a1, 201
syscall
```

What are the pros and cons of both methods? I always seen in MIPS examples the 1st method, but I can't understand wya the 2nd isn't used.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Examples don't use the second method simply to keep the example simple. A real program might use either method.

Answer (score 1):

The first method is fine in a simple program that just needs a fixed (small) number of buffers. And there's no need to free the memory, which makes it simpler for a beginner.

The dynamic allocation method offers greater flexibility over your process' memory usage.
For example, you might have a buffer that you only need temporarily, and since memory is a finite resource you might want to allocate that memory dynamically so that you can free it when you no longer need it - rather than having statically allocated memory that will remain allocated for the entire lifespan of your process.
There's also the possibility that you don't know exactly how much memory you're going to need at compile-time, because it might depend e.g. on some user input. That's another scenario when dynamic memory allocation is useful.

The downside of allocating memory dynamically is that you (the programmer) have to keep track of all of your allocations. That is, you have to make sure that you free the memory that you've allocated at some point, but you also need to make sure that your program is done with that piece of memory before you free it (or you could end up with dangling pointers).